# Como armazenar valores de Checkboxes previamente marcadas?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Olá. Estou fazendo um sistema que permissão de acessos à pastas. Busco a pasta, que tem seu id e permissões salvos no banco, a seleciono, carregando suas subpasta e checkboxes são carregados para determinar as permissões que os usuários terão a elas. Só que, ao buscar outra pasta, essa, previamente selecionada, sumirá da pagina. Gostaria de salvar os valores setados nos checkboxes.

Função que monta a lista de pastas e o checkboxes de permissões:

```
function monta_arvore(a){
          $.each(a.pastasFilhas, function(){
            $("#trazPastas").append("<tr id='pasta"+$(this)[0].id+"'><td id='temFilho"+$(this)[0].id+"'><td style='padding-left:"+$(this)[0][0].margem_esq+"'><input id=checkTds"+$(this)[0].id+" onchange=checarTdsPerm("+$(this)[0].id+") type='checkbox'>"+$(this)[0].id+" "+$(this)[0].nome+"</td></td><td style='left:0'><TD WIDTH='17' ALIGN='CENTER'><input type='checkbox' pastaChecada = "+$(this)[0].id+" id=pasta_ver-"+$(this)[0].id+" class='checarTudo'></TD><TD WIDTH='17' ALIGN='CENTER'><input type='checkbox' pastaChecada = "+$(this)[0].id+" id='pasta_criar-"+$(this)[0].id+"' class='checarTudo'></TD><TD WIDTH='17' ALIGN='CENTER'><input type='checkbox' pastaChecada = "+$(this)[0].id+" id='pasta_excluir-"+$(this)[0].id+"' class='checarTudo'></TD><TD WIDTH='17' ALIGN='CENTER'><input type='checkbox' pastaChecada = "+$(this)[0].id+" id='pasta_renomear-"+$(this)[0].id+"' class='checarTudo'></TD><TD WIDTH='17' ALIGN='CENTER'><input type='checkbox' pastaChecada = "+$(this)[0].id+" id='pasta_mover-"+$(this)[0].id+"' class='checarTudo'></TD><TD WIDTH='17' ALIGN='CENTER'><input type='checkbox' pastaChecada = "+$(this)[0].id+" id='arquivo_criar-"+$(this)[0].id+"' class='checarTudo'></TD><TD WIDTH='17' ALIGN='CENTER'><input type='checkbox' pastaChecada = "+$(this)[0].id+" id='arquivo_excluir-"+$(this)[0].id+"' class='checarTudo'></TD><TD WIDTH='17' ALIGN='CENTER'><input type='checkbox' pastaChecada = "+$(this)[0].id+" id='arquivo_renomear-"+$(this)[0].id+"' class='checarTudo'></TD><TD WIDTH='17' ALIGN='CENTER'><input type='checkbox' pastaChecada = "+$(this)[0].id+" id='arquivo_mover-"+$(this)[0].id+"' class='checarTudo'></TD><td></tr>");
            if($(this)[0].filhos){
              $("#checkTds"+$(this)[0].id).after("<td style='display:inline-block;'><div><a href='javascript:geraFilho("+$(this)[0].id+","+$(this)[0][0].margem_esq+17+")'><img id='mais"+$(this)[0].id+"' src='../imagens/icon-arrow-down-b-16.png' alt='+' height='14px' width='10px'></a></td>");
            }
          });

        }
```

Função que lê as checkboxes:

```
function testeLeituraPermissões(){
var i=0;
var objetoPermissoesPastas = function(){};

var objPermissoesPastas = new objetoPermissoesPastas();

$.each($(".checarTudo"), function(){
  objPermissoesPastas[$(this)[0].id] = 0
  i++;
});

var permissoes = [];

$.each($(".checarTudo:checked"), function(){
    objPermissoesPastas[$(this)[0].id] = 1;
});
}
```

Gostaria de saber se tem como salvar, se pode ser salvo na sessão, o id das pastas e as permissões?

Obrigado.

Comment: Muda todos os `$(this)[0]` para `this` estás a encapsular sem necessidade.

Comment: Estás a mudar de página ou somente a carregar novo conteúdo que sobreescreve as checkboxes?